# Python elif else syntaxError

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax, conditional-statements

whenever i try to use else and elif i get that error .

```
x=4
if x>0:
 print("positive")
elif x=4:
 print("equal")
else:
 print("negative")
```

Msg Error :

```
File " '<'stdin'>' ", line 1 
elif x=4 :
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "'<'stdin'>'", line 1
    else:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `elif x=4:` -> `elif x == 4:`

Comment: Thanks a lot dude ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=` is an assignment operator.

`==` is a comparison operator.

You need to use the comparison operator in the `elif` statement like so:

```
x = 4
if x > 0:
    print("positive")
elif x == 4:
    print("equal")
else:
    print("negative")
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are using assignment operator `=` instead of equality operator `==`.

```
x=4
if x>0:
 print("positive")
elif x==4:
 print("equal")
else:
 print("negative")
```